# OAuth automatic login without user clicking 'LogIn' button

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, scribe

I am trying to login to Facebook using the OAuth log-in mechanism of Scribe which builds a URL `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1928545420713067&redirect_uri=http://localhost:23080/integration/auth/facebook/callback&state=a5312c35-ab4f-4690-8086-b6ff6b249f52`

It now redirects me to a browser with a login dialog, where I need to enter my username and password and login and then OAuthService triggers the callback.

Is there a way to automate the login mechanism without me typing the 'UserName' and 'Password'values everytime I trigger Oauth authentication but store it somewhere and use it automatically whenever I need to login.

I basically want to get rid off the login dialog and take care of logging-in completely in the back end.

Comment: _“I basically want to get rid off the login dialog and take care of logging-in completely in the back end.”_ – that is not possible; login needs user interaction. _“t now redirects me to a browser with a login dialog, where I need to enter my username and password and login”_ – that’s because you are not already logged in to Facebook in the browser then. If you were, and had authorized the app before, it would redirect straight back without asking the user for any further action.

Comment: Your problem is resolved or not?

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right, You are not using OAuth correctly in first place. To solve the problem you are facing OAuth has given the solution of providing a token instead of password.

On each successful login using OAuth, you will get a token and userid in response. This need to be used next time from program to request user's personal information.

Moreover, you have to atleast allow user to enter username password on authentic facebook screen. In OAuth flow, actual password is never known to requesting site.

See flow here

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: "Moreover, you have to atleast allow user to enter username password on authentic facebook screen." Can't I pass the username and password in the post request itself instead of manually entering it everytime in the login dialog. My requirement is have a technical user to generate an access token every hour and put it in a database so that  the other users can use it to access the account.

Comment: Yes, if you have access token, you will be passing it using OAuth protocol